# why changes date format after splitting string to array vba

Tags: arrays, vba, date, split

When I split a string of dates separate by space the format goes from dd:mm:yyyy to mm:dd:yyyy with some of items

before split:

```
13-04-2022 
12-04-2022 
11-04-2022 
10-04-2022 
09-04-2022 
08-04-2022 
07-04-2022 
06-04-2022 
05-04-2022 
04-04-2022 
03-04-2022 
02-04-2022 
01-04-2022 
31-03-2022 
30-03-2022
```

after split:

```
13-04-2022
4-12-2022
4-11-2022
4-10-2022
4-9-2022
4-8-2022
4-7-2022
4-6-2022
4-5-2022
4-4-2022
4-3-2022
4-2-2022
4-1-2022
31-03-2022
30-03-2022
```

```
Dim dateinput() As String
    
    dateinput = Split(html.getElementById("pagecontent_Onbalansprijs_ddlDateSelection").innerText)        
        
    Dim item As Variant
    i = 1

   For Each item In dateinput()    
      Range("F" & i).Value = item
      i = i + 1
   Next item
```

Comment: As you can see it's doing it on the dates which can be changed (as in any dates that are under 12/12 since they can be interchangable. You must have some settings that default to mm/dd/yyyy. You should be able to just do `Range("F" & i).Value = Format(item, "dd-mm-yyyy")`

Answer (score 0):

Convert your text dates to true *Date* values:

```vb
    Range("F" & i).Value = DateSerial(Mid(item, 7), Mid(item, 4, 2), Mid(item, 1, 2))
```

Comment: Yeah this is the way. I realised my method wouldn't work for an array of dates.